Checksums for data dumps should be included in the dump announcement and on the dump download page itself
Following on from my previous request for current checksums
I'm looking at 2 use cases for a data dump:

verifying if a current download for a data dump is correct
verifying if a specific historical data dump file is correct.

For the former, it makes a lot of sense to embed the checksum into the download page - you're already including the size, which I suspect is generated with the dump creation.
For historical dumps, since we no longer have the dumps in a 'single' place - could we include a full list of checksums organically in the announcement of a dump release - it seems messy to have a specific request per data dump or a separate post after data dump release?

Are you sure that there will be continued announcements of dumps? I do agree with this, but I'm under the impression that people will have to go to the settings page, which has the date the dump was generated, to see if there will be a new dump. Anyone downloading the dump would have to record the checksum themselves.

How else would we know a new dump is out?

@testing-for-ya It seems like data dumps are not a priority. I wouldn't expect anything that requires a time investment. There have been a few features talked about - bundling mains and metas again, global download pages. But I honestly would expect the bare minimum effort when it comes to future dumps, including the effort needed to make or edit a meta post. I do expect the schedule to be held, but that people would need to go to the download page to see the last updated time.

@testing-for-ya It's not cynicism, but realism based on what I see and experience first hand. I believe in asking for things that make sense and not asking for things that are unlikely or don't make sense. I would rather expect less and then be pleasantly surprised. I do not expect continued work on data dumps after the next quarter or so.
